# Postgres : Query for searching first, last and middle names with different combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three column names that represents person name.

> first_name ; middle_name ; last_name

for example (sample data):

> Kyle      M       Bluth 
>   Kyle Nova   H       John Jr. 
>   Bluth St.    D     Kevin Dos
>   Vanakala   Vara Prasad   Raja Ravi

serach criteria like this:

> kyle   bluth
>   M   kyle
>   Raja   prasad
>   Ravi   vara
>   Bluth   Kevin   Dos

I wrote query like this:(with running loop)

```
(first_name || ' ' || last_name) like '%entered name%'
```

But, results were not accurate.
How can i get accurate results.?

Comment: if you need to match ANY of the - use OR, if you want to match combinations, use AND OR with parenthesis

Comment: Write the [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) to convert your three columns to the [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) of words; create  [GIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin.html) [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) on it; split your search criteria to array of words too and use `@>, <@ or &&` [arrays comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#array-operators-table) to get the desired result.

Comment: Hi Abelisto.. i wrote query something like this : 
`select s.staff_id, s.first_name, s.middle_initial, s.last_name from staff ds 
where array[s.first_name, s.middle_initial, s.last_name] @> array['kyle','bluth'];`..
but i'm getting error : 
**SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**